# Mysql PHP change row value then move to different DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using this to change a value in a table with a html form.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET XXX='$YYY' WHERE id='$id'")

or die(mysql_error());
```

I'm looking for it to change the value and move it to a new DB after I hit submit.

Comment: After 4 hours, your question has no activity.  This is because your question is unclear and short on information.  When you say "move" do you mean remove from original table and save to new table?  Or update it at the original table and copy the new value to the new table?

Comment: You also need to upgrade to mysqli_ functions, and protect your query from injection threats.

Comment: I want to update the row, copy it to a different table and delete it from the original table.

Comment: Your question is too light on details.  Your coding attempt isn't much of an attempt.  Please improve your question.